# How can I edit joomla files from a server in my computer?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I'm working on a joomla website and I'm having some problems with those joomla file editors (components). I'd like to edit the files in my pc and save them automatically to the server. The only user/pw I have is the superadmin in joomla.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please note that the OP apparently does not have ftp credentials. Even though filezilla and notepad++ are really good programs, the answers seem irrelevant...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have the FTP username and password then there is no way, you will have to use one of the Joomla file manager components. If you can't get the FTP info try NinjaXplorer, it seems to be the best of the file system management tools.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/file-management/4746

Answer (score 1):

If you can get ftp access, use [PhpStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/), it will help you to efficiently edit php (and most type of) files.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [PSpad](http://www.pspad.com/) connected via ftp (it has build-in ftp client) to edit files on server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) with nppftp plugin. It's easy and fast. With this plug-in, you can directly edit files from server.

Answer (score 0):

Download [filezilla](http://filezilla-project.org/). It works wonders for me.